# Generic Containers in Delphi

Tags: delphi, generics, containers

I'm trying to do this:

```
   type
      TItemRec = record
        Sender    : TAction;
        OwnerPack : HModule;
        ChildForm : TForm;
      end;
      TRecList = TList<TItemRec>;

      THelperList = class helper for TRecList
        function FindSenderIndex(ASender: TAction): Int16;
      end;
   var
      MyObj : TRecList;
```

Where *FindSenderIndex* function (implementing it still) will return index of the item where **ASender** matchs with **MyObj[i].Sender**. But when compiling I get this error message: `"E2086 Type 'TList<T>' is not yet completely defined"`

What am I doing bad? Thanks in advance.

Pdta: May you give me some good examples about how to use Object Containers `(TObjectList<T:class>=class(TList<T>))`?

Comment: Can I ask why you are using a class helper here? Why not do something like:

  TRecList = class(TList<TItemRec)
  public
    function FindSenderIndex(ASender: TAction): Int16;
  end;

As far as I know, class helpers are only meant to be used to extend classes that you don't control. You quite clearly have control of TRecList.

Comment: You are right, and I did it so, I was playing with Helper only. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This looks like a bug in the compiler. I'm able to reproduce this under Delphi 2010.  Please report it in QC.

The workaround's simple enough, though.  Declare

```
TRecList = class(TList<TItemRec>);
```

instead, and it works.

As for `TObjectList<T>`, it's exactly the same as `TList<T>` except that it will only accept objects, and it adds the OwnsObjects property.  If OwnsObjects is set to True, then when you free the list, or call the `Clear` or `Delete` methods, it will free all the objects removed from the list.